# Is it possible to use PGP subkeys in multiple emails without correlating them?

Tags: encryption, public-key, pgp

I would like to know if sub-public keys of PGP keys can be published separately, if I create a pair of master keys and multiple sub keys to be used in multiple emails, and normally use only the sub keys to encrypt, decrypt and sign. But then won't it be discovered by others that these emails are actually one person?
I'm new to cryptography and asymmetric encryption, so maybe this question is a bit silly

Comment: By 'pair of master keys' do you mean _two_ master keys, or _one_ master key containing private (aka secret) and public halves? If the latter, subkeys are signed by the masterkey and everyone can see that yours are signed by the same masterkey. If you remove the signatures they can't, but then anyone desiring to send email to you cannot determine if the key is yours or an adversary's (only masterkeys have userids) and must assume any email they send with this key is compromised, so in practice they won't send anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which means that if you want each email to be seen as a different person, it is better to create a unique master key for them.